# Show all schemas in PostGIS -> QGIS Dialog

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I am connecting to a Postgres/PostGIS database using QGIS. Within my database are a few schemas. However, in QGIS I only see the public schema, but not the others schema that are within the database. How would I display all schemas?

Comment: Normally you should see all schemas. Even if you don't have the permission to do anything on the schema you should be able to see the schema (same for pgAdmin).

Comment: @BerndLoigge I see them in the Browser Panel, but when I go to 'Layer - Add Layer - PostGIS' I do not see all the schemas, only public.

Comment: Ok, then it is a security issue that the user you use to connect to the database doesn't have the rights to see the schemas.

Comment: @BerndLoigge Really? Why can I see it in the browser panel, but not when I go through the menue? How would I give the permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QGIS is filtering out all schemas where you don't have permission on any possible data / layer (wouldn't make sense to show it). But that's handled by QGIS. Even though you don't have permission you can always see a schema / table in postgres ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017386/postgresql-hiding-tables-from-user)).
To give your user the appropriate permissions you need to have another user that has more privileges. With this user you can then [alter](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-grant/) your user and grant at least `SELECT` rights:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA someschema TO someuser;
```

**Update - how to create a Database Connection**

1. In the sidebar click the Postgres Icon
2. Choose Postgres Connection
3. Click New
4. Fill in your DB connection details
5. Click the + Icon for adding a  new authentication
6. Add your credentials (PG User)

[image]

After adding a new connection you can directly add a layer via the tree, in this dialog by clicking `Connect` or you can use the [`DB Manager`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#the-db-manager) where you can also write SQL statements.

Comment: Thanks. but how do I connect with this user to the database from QGIS?

Comment: I would recommend granting the privileges using a tool like pgAdmin or psql via the command line. if you have another user with more privileges you can create another connection using those credentials in QGIS

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know where to execute these lines. But in QGIS, I do not connect with a user. I simply start the QGIS App... Which user would I add with `GRANT SELECT ...`

Comment: you are writing you are connecting to postgres using QGIS in your question. I cant help you. your questions dont make sense.

Comment: Hm... In the QGIS Gui there is a Dialog which opens upon `Add Layer - Add PostGIS Layer`. When I add a new connection there, I only add information like `Name, Service, Host, Port, Database`. Thats it. Where to choose a user there?

Comment: I updated my answer